# how to replace bootstrap-table column's value by ajax load data

Tags: ajax, bootstrap-table

my bootstrap-table init as

```
$(function() {
// bootstrap table初始化
$table.bootstrapTable({
    url: '${basePath}/manage/carmaster/list',
    height: getHeight(),
    striped: true,
    search: true,
    showRefresh: true,
    showColumns: true,
    minimumCountColumns: 2,
    clickToSelect: true,
    detailView: true,
    detailFormatter: 'detailFormatter',
    pagination: true,
    paginationLoop: false,
    sidePagination: 'server',
    silentSort: false,
    smartDisplay: false,
    escape: true,
    searchOnEnterKey: true,
    idField: 'id',
    sortName: 'id',
    sortOrder: 'desc',
    maintainSelected: true,
    toolbar: '#toolbar',
    columns: [
        {field: 'ck', checkbox: true},
        {field: 'id', title: '编号', sortable: true, align: 'center'},
        {field: 'brand', title: '品牌'},
        {field: 'category', title: '车系'},
        {field: 'categoryDetail', title: '车名'},
        {field: 'frameNo', title: '车架号'},
        {field: 'engineNo', title: '发动机号'},
        {field: 'status', title: '状态', align: 'center',formatter: 'typeFormatter'},
        {field: 'effectiveDate', title: '投入时间',formatter: 'timeFormatter'},
        {field: 'quitDate', title: '退出时间',formatter: 'timeFormatter'},
        {field: 'useBranch', title: '使用网点'},
        {field: 'plateNo', title: '车牌号'},
        {field: 'action', title: '操作', align: 'center', formatter: 'actionFormatter', events: 'actionEvents', clickToSelect: false}
    ]
});
```

and the follow is the format function

function typeFormatter(value, row, index) {

```
console.log(value);
$.get('${basePath}/manage/dict/getCodeDesc',{dictId:value,tableName:'T_CAR_STATUS'},function(data){
    return '<span class="label label-primary">'+data+'</span>';
});
```

i wan to replace the type code by ajax load data,but it sames does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want to use a per-row per-field lookup using an asynchronous Ajax call to load "status" field values. I don't think you can achieve this in bootstrap-table using the formatter functions.

Specifically, the sample `typeFormatter()` method you included uses an asynchronous `get()` call. As-is, it does not do what you are hoping, but more than that the bootstrap-table formatter functions need to be synchronous (return a value immediately) so your current solution will not work.

HTML-wise you can do partial-page updates of the form you hope for, but bootstrap-table does not support this. See the bootstrap-table [methods documentation](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/#methods), in particular the `load`, `append`, `prepend` and `refresh` methods. These methods allow the updating of the **entire table's** data only.

If you want to achieve the individual lookups that you describe, you should use the "[From data](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#options/from-data.html)" example, update the data using Ajax calls and then refresh the table display using the `load` method (see [this](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#methods/load.html) example).

Comment: Thank you,I had read the document ,but i can not find a way to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I know this topic is old but here is my solution for this probleme :

```
function imgFormatter(value, row, index) {
     if (row.Img !== undefined && row.Img !== null) {
         return getImage(row,row.Img);
      } else if (row.ImgId > 0) {
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: url,
                 data: { id: row.ImgId },
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function(data) {
                     var newRow = row;
                     newRow.Img = data.Img;
                     $(tableId).bootstrapTable('updateRow', { index: index, row: newRow});
                 },
                 error: function(er) {
                      params.error(er);
                 }
            });
     } else {
          return getImage(row,defaultImage);
     } 
};
function getImage(row,base64Img){
   if (row.IsAdmin) {
        return '<div class="image"><div class="img"><img src="data:image/jpg;base64,' +
            base64Img +
            '" class="img-circle" width="50px"><i class="fas fa-asterisk icon-remove delete"data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body" title="Admin"></i></div></div>';
    }
    return '<div class="image"><div class="img"><img src="data:image/jpg;base64,' +
        base64Img +
        '" class="img-circle" width="50px"></div></div>';
}
```

Comment: GENIUS answer here, my friend!  THANK YOU!  I was trying to figure out how to incorporate images into my bootstrapTables, and this solution works like a CHARM!